# Correlated discrete random variable generated by Markov Chains

Tags: statistics, markov-chains, correlation

I am dealing with following problem.

I have $n=10$ weather stations and for each station I have information about wind direction: a discrete variable with 4 states $\{s, n, w, e\}$.

If I need generate wind direction scenarios for one station I am using a first order Markov chain. But now I need to generate scenarios for all weather stations and i need to include correlation between wind directions for each stations.

Any idea how to model this  situation?

Comment: Cuff P (2008) Communication Requirements for Generating Correlated Random Variables. 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.0065

Comment: Could you add some details how you are generate wind direction scenarios for one stations using first order Markov chains?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257830/correlation-for-a-discrete-time-markov-chain